# How to make fractal plants with l-system in turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make [this fractal plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system#Example_7:_Fractal_plant) (Example 7) from Wikipedia. However, even though I use the same rules I end up with something that looks more like a tree. Here is the code:

```
def fraktal_plante(padde, depth):
    Xmerke(padde, depth-1)       # X

def Xmerke(padde, depth):
    if depth > 0:
        padde.forward(12)
        padde.right(25)
        pos1 = padde.position()
        head1 = padde.heading()
        Xmerke(padde, depth-1)
        padde.up()
        padde.goto(pos1)
        padde.setheading(head1)
        padde.down()
        padde.left(25)
        Xmerke(padde, depth-1)
        padde.up()
        padde.goto(pos1)
        padde.setheading(head1)
        padde.down()
        padde.left(25)
        padde.forward(12)
        pos2 = padde.position()
        head2 = padde.heading()
        padde.left(25)
        padde.forward(12)
        Xmerke(padde, depth-1)
        padde.up()
        padde.goto(pos2)
        padde.setheading(head2)
        padde.down()
        padde.right(25)
        Xmerke(padde, depth-1)

    def Fmerke (padde, depth):
        if depth > 0:
            padde.forward(12)
            padde.forward(12)
```

Can you help me? I am new to python so please explain in an easy way!

Answer (score 6):

I think the reason you have a tree is your `.forward()` step is too large. Try `paddle.forward(1)` instead of `12`.

For what it is worth, here is what I wrote from the wikipedia description:

```
import turtle
import sys

def generate(n, result='[X]'):
    for _ in range(n):
        # rule #2
        result = result.replace('F', 'FF')
        # rule #1
        result = result.replace('X', 'F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X')

    return result

def draw(cmds, size=2):
    stack = []
    for cmd in cmds:
        if cmd=='F':
            turtle.forward(size)
        elif cmd=='-':
            turtle.left(25)
        elif cmd=='+':
            turtle.right(25)
        elif cmd=='X':
            pass
        elif cmd=='[':
            stack.append((turtle.position(), turtle.heading()))
        elif cmd==']':
            position, heading = stack.pop()
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setposition(position)
            turtle.setheading(heading)
            turtle.pendown()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown Cmd: {}'.format(ord(cmd)))
    turtle.update()

def setup():
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.tracer(1e3,0)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0,-turtle.window_height()/2)
    turtle.pendown()

setup()
plant = generate(6)
draw(plant, 2)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You might find my [codegolf challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/sorry-young-man-but-its-turtles-all-the-way-down) interesting. There's a Python L-system in 294 chars.

Comment: Yes, @jsetting32, I had to change the setup code to draw the dragon curve. Look here: ideone.com/RvmXFn . In `setup()`, the calls to `hideturtle()` and `tracer()` make the drawing go faster. The other calls make sure that this particular image is in the window.